# Drupal 7: Best Practice for a Dynamic Select List in Drupal 7

Tags: dynamic, drupal-7, selectlist, form-api

What is the best practice for a dynamic select list in Drupal 7?

1. Create a Field with dummy options via the UI and overriding the options with `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`

or

2. Creating a dynamic select list from scratch via a custom module with the `hook_form`

or

3. different approach?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for Drupal 7

Answer (score 22):

You could use Form API's [#ajax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#ajax) (it used to be called `#ahah` in Drupal6) to do that.

Here is an example for Drupal 7 (based on [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples)) that shows two dropdowns where the first dropdown modifies the list of options of the second dropdown:

Source of file **mymodule.module**:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 * Registers a form-based page that you can access at "http://localhost/mypage"
 */
function mymodule_menu(){
    return array(
        'mypage' => array(
            'title' => 'A page to test ajax',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('mymodule_page'),
            'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
        )
    );
}



/**
 * A form with a dropdown whose options are dependent on a
 * choice made in a previous dropdown.
 *
 * On changing the first dropdown, the options in the second are updated.
 */
function mymodule_page($form, &$form_state) {
    // Get the list of options to populate the first dropdown.
    $options_first = mymodule_first_dropdown_options();

    // If we have a value for the first dropdown from $form_state['values'] we use
    // this both as the default value for the first dropdown and also as a
    // parameter to pass to the function that retrieves the options for the
    // second dropdown.
    $value_dropdown_first = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_first']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_first'] : key($options_first);

    $form['dropdown_first'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'First Dropdown',
        '#options' => $options_first,
        '#default_value' => $value_dropdown_first,

        // Bind an ajax callback to the change event (which is the default for the
        // select form type) of the first dropdown. It will replace the second
        // dropdown when rebuilt
        '#ajax' => array(
            // When 'event' occurs, Drupal will perform an ajax request in the
            // background. Usually the default value is sufficient (eg. change for
            // select elements), but valid values include any jQuery event,
            // most notably 'mousedown', 'blur', and 'submit'.
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'dropdown_second_replace',
        ),
    );
    $form['dropdown_second'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Second Dropdown',
        // The entire enclosing div created here gets replaced when dropdown_first
        // is changed.
        '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown_second_replace">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        // when the form is rebuilt during ajax processing, the $value_dropdown_first variable
        // will now have the new value and so the options will change
        '#options' => mymodule_second_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_first),
        '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
    );
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Selects just the second dropdown to be returned for re-rendering
 *
 * Since the controlling logic for populating the form is in the form builder
 * function, all we do here is select the element and return it to be updated.
 *
 * @return renderable array (the second dropdown)
 */
function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['dropdown_second'];
}


/**
 * Helper function to populate the first dropdown. This would normally be
 * pulling data from the database.
 *
 * @return array of options
 */
function mymodule_first_dropdown_options() {
    return array(
        'colors' => 'Names of colors',
        'cities' => 'Names of cities',
        'animals' => 'Names of animals',
    );
}


/**
 * Helper function to populate the second dropdown. This would normally be
 * pulling data from the database.
 *
 * @param key. This will determine which set of options is returned.
 *
 * @return array of options
 */
function mymodule_second_dropdown_options($key = '') {
    $options = array(
        'colors' => array(
            'red' => 'Red',
            'green' => 'Green',
            'blue' => 'Blue'
        ),
        'cities' => array(
            'paris' => 'Paris, France',
            'tokyo' => 'Tokyo, Japan',
            'newyork' => 'New York, US'
        ),
        'animals' => array(
            'dog' => 'Dog',
            'cat' => 'Cat',
            'bird' => 'Bird'
        ),  
    );
    if (isset($options[$key])) {
        return $options[$key];
    }
    else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used your code above. But i cannot get the selected values. Once i change the dropdown_one, the dropdown_second is not displaying. I have made one change in you code. I have used the hook_form_form_id_alter hook instead of hook_page(). I have raised a question. Can you check and help me solve this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496574/drupal-dynamic-select-list-not-reterving-values-in-subcategory-field

Answer (score 0):

The callback for the answer from wildpeaks should be:

```
function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return render($form['dropdown_second']);
}
```